# Multiple AVG with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the follow table structure:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
1       6       1
3       3       7
4       8       9
```

I'd like to get the average of all columns. It's possible to get this with a single SQL command, with PHP prepared statements?

Thanks

Comment: In the context of an RDBMS, this isn't really a 'structure'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   AVG (COLUMN1) AS AVG1,  
   AVG (COLUMN2) AS AVG3,  
   AVG (COLUMN3) AS AVG3  
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This code works for me, but without "AS AVG1, AS AVG2...". Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to take the averages of each columns seperately. Above answer  works but another answer can be as like below;

```
SELECT 
   SUM (COLUMN1)/ COUNT(COLUMN1) AS AVG1,  
   SUM (COLUMN2)/ COUNT(COLUMN2)  AS AVG2,  
   SUM (COLUMN3)/ COUNT(COLUMN3)  AS AVG3  
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: I get the error "An alias was previously found" (PHPmyadmin)